# JqGrid Hide/Show columns

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I have an MVC project, and am working on a page using JQGrid. I have a flyout menu with lots of checkboxes (one for each column of the grid), and I am trying to attach a script to hide/show a column on click.

I've read lots of solutions, and tried using the hide/show methods from the wiki.

```
$("ShippingListGrid").hideCol("Open");
```

"Open" is the name of the column in the colModel

```
{ name: 'Open', index: 'Open', width: 120, align: 'left', editable: true,sortable: true,hidden: false,Key: false, edittype: 'text', editoptions: { size: 20, maxlength: 30}},
```

This doesn't seem to work though, when I call the function my grid does not change. I've tried reloading my grid and using the column id instead of the name, and the columns still don't change. I've got the latest download. Does anyone know why the function might not be working?

Comment: The code `$("ShippingListGrid").hideCol("Open");` or better `$("ShippingListGrid").jqGrid("hideCol","Open");` should work in general. You should include the full demo which can be used to reproduce the problem. Moreover you should consider to use [columnCooser](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jquery_ui_methods#column_chooser) for your purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Oleg, the column Chooser would be great, but my spec is to use a fly out with check boxes. I copied the html and javascript from this demo - http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html into my project and it had the same problem. So the problem is caused by my project somehow. I guess I'll build a new project and start adding components from my old one until it breaks.

Comment: @Joe: You can consider to use old [setColumns](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:show_hide_columns#calling_convention) method. In the jqGrid 4.0.0 you will find the `grid.setcolumns.js` module in the `plugins` subdirectory.

Comment: @Oleg: Thanks again, the setColumns popup will work perfectly. Still, a little worrying that the other function did not work. Even in a blank MVC 2 project, I added the html and code from the demo and it didn't work. I'll use the column chooser as you suggested, else I could spend a very long time figuring it out :P

Comment: @Joe: You can upload somewhere your test MVC 2 project and post the URL.

Comment: @Oleg: Sorry I can't upload my project. But I did just solve the issue. I was using jquery 1.4.4. I updated to 1.5.2 and the function works. So simple I'm a little embarrassed I didn't try it earlier. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

Check your selector, if your grid is a table ID, you will need the `#` symbol. Maybe try: `$("#ShippingListGrid").hideCol("Open");`